# angular2/rxjs/redux reimplementation - route change messing with observable

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs

I'm trying to do a basic reimplementation of redux in rxjs in an angular2 app.

At this point it's basically just a couple of things I found on the internets stitched together, [this plunker](https://twitter.com/robwormald/status/661865214032240640) for angular DI, [this for file structure](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/todomvc), [this for combineReducers](https://github.com/jas-chen/rx-redux) and lastly [this for "redux in rxjs"](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=563bfd3c2e8c19094ec0158e).

There' sa couple of problems I'm having, but this is at the moment the biggest: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXau87UmqOs

What's happening:

- I have two components, `index` and `todos` each has a route
- in index I only show a list of todos
- in todos I can delete and add a new todo
- when I switch between routes without adding a new todo or removing one, everything works fine
- when I add or remove a todo, it still works, new todo is appended, old is deleted, data in `console.log` looks fine
- **when I go to different route after adding or removing in todo, [observable](https://github.com/fxck/ng2-rx-redux/blob/master/src/services/NgStore.ts#L24) becomes the last redux action I called, for example** `Object {type: "DELETE_TODO", id: 1}` **instead of array of todos**

here's what I described in `console.log`s (can be seen in the youtube video as well)

```
---- index loaded ----
index.js:33 map in index: Object {todos: Array[3]}
index.js:35 resp in index: Object {todos: Array[3]}
index.js:38 ---- index destroyed ----
todos.js:31 ---- todos loaded ----
todos.js:33 map in todos: Object {todos: Array[3]}
todos.js:35 resp in todos: Object {todos: Array[3]}
todos.js:45 ---- todos destroyed ----
index.js:30 ---- index loaded ----
index.js:33 map in index: Object {todos: Array[3]}
index.js:35 resp in index: Object {todos: Array[3]}
index.js:38 ---- index destroyed ----
todos.js:31 ---- todos loaded ----
todos.js:33 map in todos: Object {todos: Array[3]}
todos.js:35 resp in todos: Object {todos: Array[3]}
NgStore.js:49 Object {type: "DELETE_TODO", id: 1}
todos.js:33 map in todos: Object {todos: Array[2]}
todos.js:35 resp in todos: Object {todos: Array[2]}
todos.js:45 ---- todos destroyed ----
index.js:30 ---- index loaded ----
index.js:33 map in index: Object {type: "DELETE_TODO", id: 1}
index.js:35 resp in index: Object {type: "DELETE_TODO", id: 1}
```

Any idea what could be causing the observable to change when route changes?

Here's the repo https://github.com/fxck/ng2-rx-redux it's usign the latest alpha(46)

Comment: Well well that looks like a question which requires to delve into a lot of different concepts. You should narrow down the scope of your question (have you at least identified which part is failing?). Your question is also imprecise : `the observable` : which one? what does it do? What are the specifications for that observable? input vs. expected output? etc.

Comment: That brings me to a general advice : WRITE TESTS for your code. I could not find any in your repertory at first sight. Maybe you have them elsewhere? You probably heard about TDD and the like before, and though it is counterintuitive to many, it actually helps getting code faster (and also getting help faster, as tests end up being a documentation of your code). If you test step by step, when something fails it is easier to picture where is the issue.

Comment: For Rxjs debugging, cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md

Comment: @user3743222 there's basically only one observable, which is the "redux" "store" itself, https://github.com/fxck/ng2-rx-redux/blob/master/src/services/NgStore.ts#L24 and I know that it's failing once I push next/new value to the behaviorsubject AND change route. But if it's angular router doing it, or my store observable, I have no idea.

Comment: also tests are apparently still pain in the ass(read work in progress) in angular2, since it's in alpha, and so is rxjs5 which ng2 is using..

Comment: Is it? PITA is part of the job description and do you really have a choice anyways? I quickly googled it and I found this about unit testing for Angular2 :  http://blog.rangle.io/unittests/. About Rxjs5, I don-t know it either (I'm using 4.0 at best), but in 4.0 there is a test suite, test tools and techniques (link mentioned in former comment). Might not be perfect but they help. In any case, somebody will have to test or debug to answer your question unless you luckily find somebody with experience in the three libraries that can picture it at first sight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `RxJS` API incorrectly. To fix your code you should do next two things:

1. Set initial state into [`scan`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md) operator.

```ts
// services/NgStore.ts

this._subject = new BehaviorSubject().scan(rootReducer, initialState);
```

2. Change condition in `switch` statement to check if `action` is empty (e.g === `undefined`):

```ts
// reducers/todo.ts

export const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action && action.type) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

**PS** I won't remove my first answer for someone who doesn't know that redux is already implemented in RxJS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement `redux` in `rxjs` because it's already implemented there. [Observable::scan(accumulator, [seed])](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md) operator does exactly the same what `redux` does. Here's a simplified example (see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/43l1NEaLXb3zheJ97Uqf?p=preview)):

```ts
// store.js
import BehaviorSubject from '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/subjects/BehaviorSubject';
import reducer from './reducer';
export default new BehaviorSubject().scan(reducer, 0)

// reducer.js
export default function(state, action) {
  switch (action && action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// app.js
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2'
import store from './store';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>{{ value }}</h2>
    <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
    <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    store.subscribe(value => this.value = value);
  }

  increment() { store.next({ type: 'INCREMENT' }) }
  decrement() { store.next({ type: 'DECREMENT' }) }
}
```

Well, of course you can reinvent the wheel (at least just for fun).

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing, I'm not using redux, rather trying to reimplement redux patterns, see https://github.com/fxck/ng2-rx-redux/blob/master/src/services/NgStore.ts#L24 except that when I change route, store becomes `{ type: 'INCREMENT' }`, rather than say `2`. Check the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXau87UmqOs

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark. A route change is a change of view state. I bet angular2 recreates or updates components which you have configured in your router. What you are describing is :

- route change and no change in model : OK
- route change and change in state in your todo model gives you wrong result.

My experience in Angular is nill but from what I read about it, my intuition is :

- If there is no change in the state, the router does not update the component (no need to as they only depend on a state which did not change right?)
- If there is a change in the state, then the router calls for updating the impacted component. Because you get back the last redux action, and you use a behaviour subject, I blind guess that it could be that you are keeping the subject alive at all times, and resubscribing on route change, and when you resubscribe, you get back the last value (that's what behaviour subject does per specs).

It is a total shot in the dark, but you should try to set up a test on those lines, at least to discard that possibility.

Comment: "If there is no change in the state, the router does not update the component" => it does, it completely removes it

Comment: Removing the component is not updating the component. Updating a component is to change the state of that component. The thing is that you have several states here. One is component state which belongs to it. And then there is the state associated with the component tree which is what you see on your screen. That state is made of the displayed/not displayed status of the components.

Comment: router hooks into components, they are linked together, so when I change route from component `<index></index>` to `<todos></todos>`, it removes whole `<index></index>`, unsubscribe everything, does cleanups and stuff. So the same thing is happening whether I change data in store or not..

Comment: but I don't really know, let me try

Comment: yes, but the component who is displayed on your screen has changed state as the underlying data model did. So the component which is not to be displayed is removed, but the one that is displayed must be updated based on the new state of the data model (or store as you call it). So if the big idea of redux is to have one state for the whole component tree, then my bet is that you/angular are resubscribing to your redux all-the-state-in-one-place subject which as a behaviour subject repeats its last value.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right, https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/AsyncPipe-class.html is doing the subscribing / unsubscribing.. So the way it's behaving is actually expected from the behaviour subject? Should I use something else than behaviour subject then?

Comment: I don't know, why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: Because one of the of angular team members told me to :) anyway, I tried using `ReplaySubject` along with `startWith(data)` rather then `BehaviorSubject(data)` and it seems to be working. The only thing is, that I don't really know why.

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md

Comment: Strange that `ReplaySubject` works then, when it's supposed to be the same as `BehaviorSubject` minus the initial data..

Comment: Well they are different. Maybe it is more clear here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html. Your confusion is probably due to the fact that a replay subject configured to replay only one value is definitely similar to a behaviour subject. However the behaviour subject also adds the notion of initial value - so it always have a value to emit to subscribers. Small differences but important differences. Anyways please accept the answer if you are happy with it.